# How to build relational tables in a two-sided marketplace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm really struggling with this problem, would love some additional thoughts. Here's the basic context:

- `Users` can both list `items` to be lent out, and make `requests` for items to borrow
- `Requests` are posted by `users` who want to borrow something. Each `request` may contain several `items`
- `Items` are predefined (i.e., POST form is a checkbox) and listed by `users` who want to lend them out, and are in turn borrowed by other `users` who have submitted a `request`

Workflow:

1. John is a user and submits a request for a tent from 6/5 to 6/8
2. The controller looks for all users (besides John) who own tents that are available from 6/5 to 6/8
3. This list of users are contacted to see who wants to provide a tent for John
4. Whoever responds affirmative to John first has their item in the table automatically updated to be no longer available from 6/5 to 6/8
5. John and the other user are connected to make the exchange happen

So far my thinking:

- `Users` table `has_many :items` and `has_many :requests`
- `Requests` table `belongs_to :users`
- `Items` table `belongs_to :users`

Additional complexities that my brain can't seem to process:

- One `request` can contain multiple `items`, and I've been told against accepting `items` as a serialized array in one cell, so then I'm not sure how to relate `request` and `item`. In the tables above, should `items` also `belong_to requests`? And if yes, this seems to imply that a `user` has to make a `request` for a specific `item` whereas I want the user to be able to search for tent, and see a list of all the users who have tents that are available
- `Requests` contain `start_date` and `end_date` attributes, that somehow need to be compared to when the `item` is available. Right now I'm thinking in the `items` table, there needs to be a column that stores the dates when the item will be in use (i.e., not available). But then this data will be an array again. For example, a tent might be requested (and the user responds OK) from 6/5 to 6/8 and then again from 6/10 to 6/15, and then again from 7/8 to 7/9. So do I need a fourth table??
- `Items` will be a predefined list, e.g., tent, sleeping bag, sleeping pad. In this way, I'm wondering do I actually need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with `users`, since a tent could belong to many users, and a user could have many tents.

Sorry if this sounds like a ramble... I've been sitting here for 4 hours with many sheets of paper and scribbles and this is not getting any clearer...

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the basic way of recording information relationally ie in tables.

**Finding sufficient tables**

Just have a base table for every statement you need to describe a business situation:

```
User(user_id,name,...)
    // User [user_id] is named [name]
Contacted(contact_id,item,offer_id)
    // user [contact_id] was contacted re item [item] offered by user [offer_id]
...etc...
```

The parameters of the statement are the columns of the table.

If you want to talk about the parts of something that you think of as having multiple parts (heterogenous or homogeneous) that just means that some statements will involve a thing and its parts:

```
table request(request_id,start_date,end_date,...)
    // [request_id] goes from [start_date] to [end_date] and ...
table requested(request_id,item_id,person_id,...)
    // person [person_id] requested item [item_id] in request [request_id]
```

**What's in a table**

A base table's value is the rows that make its statement true. (Every query subexpression also has a statement, and its value is the rows that make its statement true.)

Don't confuse table statements with business rules. Business rules state truths. But a table statement is a statement that some tuple makes true (and goes in the table) or false (is left out of the table). All the true and false statements from the tables tell you everything you need to know about the business. The business rules will never contradict them. (Since they're always true.)

**Rearranging to better tables**

A key is a set of columns that all other columns are such functions of but none of whose subsets have that property. A table can have more than one key.

To make a database easier to update and query you should break up certain statements that are other statements joined by AND. Break up until each statement consists of a statement only about key columns ANDed with statements of this form:

```
[my_column]=my_function([key_k_column_1],[key_k_column_2],...)
```

where key_k_column_1,... are columns of the same key key_n.

(Such a table is "in fifth normal form" and the topic is "normalization".)